# Coefficient matrix in AES in Decryption stage

Tags: encryption, aes, encryption-asymmetric, encryption-symmetric

I know that in AES, in encryption stage, in MixColumns, we use [4x4] coefficient matrix with values having only (00,01,02,03). Does anyone know what values are used for coefficient matrix in InvMixColumns at decryption stage? I know those coefficients occur by taking inverse of 00,01,02,03 in rajindel field. I calculated those as

```
00---------->00  
01---------->01
02---------->141
03---------->246
```

The association shown above is coefficient--------->Its inverse in Rajindel field represented in decimal. Are the values correct? I need some confirmation. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial coefficients of AES are actually:

```
03, 01, 01, 02
```

Which can be inverted to:

```
0B, 0D, 09, 0E
```

See also section 4.3 of [FIPS 197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf), particular equations (4.14), (4.15), (5.5), and (5.9).

Note that it is not as simple as inverting each coefficient in the field GF(2<sup>8</sup>). Instead, you invert the *polynomial* in the whole ring of polynomials modulo x<sup>4</sup>+1.